# How to make a ComboBoxCellEditor read-only?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a `ComboBoxCellEditor`, on which users should only be able to select the items within it, but not to edit them in the combo box.

Is there s.th like this?

```
cellEditor.setReadOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely creating it with:

```
new ComboBoxCellEditor(parent, items, SWT.READ_ONLY)
```

will do the trick?